Is the word "her " needed?
In Killers Of The Flower Moon (2023), Ernest moved to town along with his wife Mollie and meets
Bryon:

Ernest: Well, you know Mollie. She likes her nice things, so...
Bryon: Not as much as you do.

Is the word "her "  needed?

Please explain what you mean by "needed"?  Grammatically required?  Contributes nothing to the meaning and is therefore unneeded?

@TimR It's obvious what the OP means. It means is "her" required for the sentence to make sense or be grammatical.

@Lambie  I would rather that the OP speak for themselves, thank you.  OP has asked several questions now whether "X is needed". I don't think your mind-reading is helpful.

Omitting 'her' in the sentence would remove a certain nuance. We can use a possessive pronoun (his, her, their etc) to discuss someone's likes, and it serves to emphasise the fact that the person often, or habitually, has the experience that they like, e.g. he likes his wine and cigars, she likes her shopping trips, I like my roast beef, the English like their cup of tea. The usage is a little conversational and informal (but not crashingly so).

Yes, but this is different. It implies she actually has some nice things in her possession.

@Lambie - not to me it doesn't. Not automatically. Depends on context.

wine, cigars and tea are consummables. Nice things are not, that's the difference. And, if you have never had those things, you wouldn't use the pronoun. It implies you have them or have had them.

I'd have to agree with both of you. A person who likes "her nice things" has had in her life some things that she considers of higher quality, perhaps even of finest quality; she may or may not have such things at present. The possessive "her" in this locution does not entail current possession, merely the prior possession and an ongoing predilection for such fineries.  The phrase could be said of someone who lost everything in a fire, or during the Great Depression when the household's finances went belly up, or as a result of having to flee a country as a refugee, for example.

@TimR Right, exactly. If you had never had "nice things", the her would not work. But apparently that does not please some people. And I get three dvs. Unbelievable

She likes nice things.  a general statement which doesn't tell us she has any....
She likes her nice things. means she has some OR has had some and likes them. Otherwise, it would make no sense at all. Think about that for a minute...
If she has never had nice things, how can they be hers??

+1 from me. Or if it doesn’t quite mean she has some, then it at least suggests it.

@PaulTanenbaum Right, suggests is probably better but they could be physical widgets.

To me, it suggests, overwhelmingly, the meaning 'she likes to have 'nice' things (i.e. luxury/premium products). A script I found seems to bear this out (they are talking about the furnishings of a house) but, lacks the 'her' of the OP's question. ERNEST …yea. Pretty much. We’re here now. [Beat] You made yourself a nice place here. BILL SMITH Yeah, the Shoun brothers gave us a
sweet deal. Left us some nice things here, too. [Beat] Not as
nice as you’ve been buying, but it’s enough for us. ERNEST Mollie likes nice things. BILL SMITH Not as much as you... The added 'her' fits this.

@MichaelHarvey That arguement is very convoluted. The guy is just making a general statement about Mollie.

"You know John. He likes his cigars". Doesn't particularly imply that he has any cigars right now. In fact, it's quite possible that the reason for saying it might be to suggest that they should give John one or more cigars, since he definitely likes them, but currently hasn't got any.

@FumbleFingers - exactly.

@FumbleFingers Yes, but not in this case. I just don't get how "she likes her nice things" works like that here. And doing what Michael did, getting a script and adding the pronoun is a bit much, as an arguement. When you use the pronoun it implies they have or have had the things. Otherwise, it would make no sense. Cigars, wine etc. are not exactly like "nice things". If you have never had them, one wouldn't say that about you.

And doing what Michael did, getting a script and adding the pronoun is a bit much - I didn't 'add the pronoun'; it as in the OP's question, but not the script.

@Lambie: I'd say She likes her nice things is pretty much the same as She likes having nice things, but when we say John likes his cigars that's more like John likes smoking cigars. And Jane likes her movies means Jane likes watching movies, not that she necessarily possesses a movie library (perhaps she only watch movies in the cinema).

@FumbleFingers Yes, each case is individual. But here, if she likes her nice things, it means she has them or has had them. There is just no doubt about that. And I don't think likes having nice things is the same as likes her nice things.

@MichaelHarvey You did add it with this comment: The added 'her' fits this. The more dvs I receive the better.

Disregard t he downvotes: they are wrong. You can't say: She likes her nice things, if she ain't got any.
